# Is it possible to use onchange on base select option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to use a submit `onchange` on this select option. I know I can do it on the `<% f.select%>` one with `:onchange => 'this.form.submit()')`, but I can't find any documentation on how to do it on this select statement.

```
<%= form_for(@profile_option, remote: true) do |form| %>

    <div class="form-group" id="profile_options_budgetid" >
      <div class="h7 text">Select Budget to Show</div>
         <select class="custom-select" name="profile_options[budget_id]" id="profile_options_budgetid">
           <option disabled value="" selected hidden>Please Select</option>
           <% Budget.where(user_id:current_user).each do |budget| %>
           <option value=<%= budget.id %>> Budget: <%= budget.month %> <%= budget.year %>
            </option>
                                            
             <% end %>
         </select>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out
`<select class="custom-select" name="user_option[budget_id]" id="user_option_budgetid" onchange="this.form.submit()">`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
<%= select_tag 'your_column', options_for_select(@val_arr, @selected_val), class: 'date-control your_column' %>

$( "#your_column" ).change(function() {
    var your_column = $("#your_column option:selected" ).text();
    $("#your_column").val(your_column);
    $('form').submit();
});
```

- your_column = which you want in on change event.

it's work for me.